# how use global variable in javascript for main and newwindow

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, button, click

I have two jsp(one is main page, another one is new window) and single javascript file.

MainPage and New Window have **'Test'** , **'ClickedCount'** buttons.

First, I click **3** times in MainPage **'Test'** button .  Then i open New Window.
Now , i click  **2** times in newWindow **'Test'** button.
So totally i clicked **5** times.

each time i click, i count the button click in javascript.

But  mainwindow shows only **3** times, --> **getTestButtonClickedCount**()
And new window shows only **2** times . --> **getTestButtonClickedCount**()

Here i use same single javascript file (**count.js**)

So how to get total clickCount both window (mainWindow + NewWindow) **'Test'** button.

**MainWindow.jsp**

```
<html>
     <head>
          <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"> 
          <script src="count.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
     </head>
<body>
 <input type="button" value="Test" onclick="countTestButtonClick()"/>
 <input type="button" value="ClickedCount" onclick="getTestButtonClickedCount();"/>

 <a href="#" onclick = "window.open('NewWindow.jsp','newwindow',
                        'width=400,height=200')">Click to open New window</a>
</body>
</html>
```

**NewWindow.jsp**

```
<html>
     <head>
           <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"> 
           <script src="count.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
     </head>
<body>
  <input type="button" value="Test" onclick="countTestButtonClick()"/>
  <input type="button" value="ClickedCount" onclick="getTestButtonClickedCount();"/>
</body>
</html>
```

**count.js**

```
var clickCount = 0;

function countTestButtonClick()
{    
    clickCount++;
}

function getTestButtonClickedCount()
{
   alert("Total Number of clicked : " + clickCount);
}
```

Help me about this.
Thanks for your effort.

Comment: @eswaramoorthy-nec - would be nice if you accept some answers to your prev questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the JS from the newWindow and change to

```
 <input type="button" value="Test" onclick="opener.countTestButtonClick()"/>
 <input type="button" value="ClickedCount" onclick="opener.getTestButtonClickedCount();"/>
```

Alternatively if one window does not open the other, use a cookie to store the clicks, reading it in and updating it and storing it each time